# Bootstrapper and Setup in Add/Remove Programs

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, addremoveprograms

I have a custom bootstrapper CustomBA and an application setup AppSetup.

I only want the AppSetup to be visible in the Add/Remove Programs so I removed the name of the Bootstrapper. This ensures that it is not there in the Add/Remove Programs.

I have a custom uninstaller for the AppSetup which is called from a program menu shortcut. This however does not remove the Bootstrapper entry in the Registry.

Should I add a custom action to remove the bootstrapper registry entry or is there a more direct approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation says this, have you set these Attributes (DisableModify & DisableRemove) in your bundle?

> If the "DisableModify" attribute is also "yes" or "button" then the
>   bundle will not be displayed in Progams and Features and another
>   mechanism (such as registering as a related bundle addon) must be used
>   to ensure the bundle can be removed.

DisableRemove   YesNoType    Determines whether the bundle can be removed via the Programs and Features (also known as Add/Remove Programs). If the value is "yes" then the "Uninstall" button will not be displayed. The default is "no" which ensures there is an "Uninstall" button to remove the bundle. If the "DisableModify" attribute is also "yes" or "button" then the bundle will not be displayed in Progams and Features and another mechanism (such as registering as a related bundle addon) must be used to ensure the bundle can be removed.

[LINK](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_bundle.htm)

Comment: This only answers part of the question, as `DisableRemove="yes" DisableModify="yes"` disables the bootstrapper from showing up in Programs and Features, but it does not answer the second part of the question, which is how to display the user's AppSetup (other MSI package) in Programs and Features (something I am also interested in doing).

Comment: And I think the answer to that it to set Visible on the MsiPackage element: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html

Comment: This only removes Remove and Modify buttons.  If you uninstall the package then rerun the bundle installation it will ask if you would like to modify or uninstall, because it's still installed.